# PGP: How to revocate subkey using designated revocation key?

Tags: cryptography, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

According to [RFC4880](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4880#section-5.2.1) i can revocate main key, subkeys, direct-key signatures and certification signatures not only by key being revoked but by authorized revocation key too.

> 0x20: Key revocation signature
> The signature is calculated directly on the key being revoked.  A
> revoked key is not to be used.  Only revocation signatures by the
> key being revoked, **or by an authorized revocation key**, should be
> considered valid revocation signatures.
>
> 0x28: Subkey revocation signature
> The signature is calculated directly on the subkey being revoked.
> A revoked subkey is not to be used.  Only revocation signatures
> by the top-level signature key that is bound to this subkey, **or
> by an authorized revocation key**, should be considered valid
> revocation signatures.
>
> 0x30: Certification revocation signature
> This signature revokes an earlier User ID certification signature
> (signature class 0x10 through 0x13) or direct-key signature
> (0x1F).  It should be issued by the same key that issued the
> revoked signature **or an authorized revocation key**.  The signature
> is computed over the same data as the certificate that it
> revokes, and should have a later creation date than that
> certificate.

I authorized one but i cant use it to revocate subkeys. I tried to use **revkey** command in --edit-key mode. But it only use primary key to which subkey belongs. I tried to delete secret key to forse to use authorized secret key but it saying that secrte key not found.

Comment: I'd suggest to edit your question, clarifying that you use GnuPG in your experiments. Most likely you should look for --desig-revoke command (however I didn't try it ).

Comment: thank you, i missed this command somehow!

Comment: After further investigations found out that this feature is not available yet: https://dev.gnupg.org/T4370